# What the server-to-server responseBody looks like?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

What the server-to-server responseBody looks like and how should i know if a user cancelled subscription or refunded?
I have seen this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody, but still confused.I have not seen a field like `cacellation_date`.
Should i parse the `latest_receipt_info`, and then if user cacel subscription, there will be `cacellation_data` and `cacallataion_intent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cancellation fields are only for the case that the Apple Support cancelled the subscription for a customer. In that case you get the `cancellation_date_ms` field in the server-to-server response.

> **cancellation_date_ms**
>
> The time and date that Apple customer support canceled a transaction or the time and date the user upgraded an auto-renewable subscription.

more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/cancellation_date_ms).

`cancellation_date` is the corresponding field in the receipt itself.

**Note:** `cancellation_date` and `cancellation_date_ms` both only exist in the *production* environment.

To check if a user cancelled your subscription, you would use `expiration_intent` (The reason a subscription expired).

> You can use this value to:
>
> - Decide whether to survey the subscribers who have opted in to an account on your system or show alternative subscription products within the same group, if the value is “1”.
> - Decide whether to show the same or alternative subscription products, if the value is “2”, since the user did not actively make the choice to unsubscribe.
> - Decide whether to present a subscription offer to win back the user if the value is "1".

more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/expiration_intent)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, is there a different between cancelling a auto-renewable subscription on device and Apple Customer Support?

Comment: Canceling a subscription as user only prevents the renewal. So the subscription remains valid till its expiration date, but won't renew after it expires. If Apple Support cancels the subscription it is instantly invalid and the user gets his money back.

Comment: Got it. Much appreciate. As server-to-server notificatoin_type 'CANCEL' states that it is the event that cancelling subscription on Apple Customer Support or updating the subscription. Then, as far as user prevent renewal, is there a notification? If there is, what the notification type?

Comment: Disable auto-renewal triggers `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS`